# Parse Url querystring with delphi 5

Tags: parsing, delphi, query-string

I have this string:

> Called=%2B12608883475&ToState=IN&CallerCountry=US&Direction=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CAb7faaa30058c2347a595630f2475113a&To=%2B12608883475&CallerZip=

I would like to parse it by `&` to get all the parameters out and then sort the parameters in an alphabetical case-sensitive order.

All of this has to be done in Delphi 5:

```pascal
Function TwilioSignatureValidate(twilioSignature: string; QueryString: string ; Url: string): boolean;
begin
  parameters := QueryString;
  List := TStringList.Create;
end;
```

Here is the C# version that I want to copy:

```cs
string input = "Called=%2B12608883475&ToState=IN&CallerCountry=US&Direction=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CAb7faaa30058c2347a595630f2475113a&To=%2B12608883475&CallerZip=";

Dictionary<string,string> keyValuePairs = input.Split('&')
    .Select(value => value.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);

string studentId = keyValuePairs["StudentId"];
```

Using List.Sort;

I got my Delphi List To sort alphebetically but its not in using Unix-style case-sensitive sorting order:
//Delphi Sort
https://ffbc1360.ngrok.io
AccountSidACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf461957a5a626
ApiVersion2010-04-01
Called+12608883475
CalledCity
CalledCountryUS
CalledStateIN
CalledZip
Caller+12602060582
CallerCity
CallerCountryUS
CallerStateIN
CallerZip
CallSidCAb7faaa30058c2347a595630f2475113a
CallStatusringing
Directioninbound
From+12602060582
FromCity
FromCountryUS
FromStateIN
FromZip
To+12608883475
ToCity
ToCountryUS
ToStateIN
ToZip

//Correct c# Sort
https://ffbc1360.ngrok.io
AccountSidACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf461957a5a626
ApiVersion2010-04-01
CallSidCAb7faaa30058c2347a595630f2475113a
CallStatusringing
Called+12608883475
CalledCity
CalledCountryUS
CalledStateIN
CalledZip
Caller+12602060582
CallerCity
CallerCountry
USCaller
StateIN
CallerZip
Directioninbound
From+12602060582
FromCity
FromCountryUS
FromStateIN
FromZip
To+12608883475
ToCity
ToCountryUS
ToStateIN
ToZip

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: How would I sort my query string into a list, I am new to Delphi.

Comment: Posting code that is almost entirely commented out is as useless as posting no code at all. The code you posted is clearly not your effort  with Delphi 5, as Delphi 5 did not support generics or TStringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

`TStringList` in Delphi 6 and later has `Delimiter`, `DelimitedText`, and `CaseSensitive` properties.  Set the `Delimiter` to `'&'` and then assign the query string to `DelimitedText`, then you can use the `Values[]` property to extract values by name (since the resulting delimited strings are already in `name=value` format). No sorting is needed:

```pascal
Function TwilioSignatureValidate(twilioSignature: string; QueryString: string ; Url: string): boolean;
var
  List: TStringList;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    List.Delimiter := '&';
    List.DelimitedText := QueryString;
    List.CaseSensitive := True;

    // use List.Values['param name'] as needed, eg:
    // List.Values['Called']
    // List.Values['ToState']
    // List.Values['CallerCountry']
    // List.Values['Direction']
    // List.Values['CallerState']
    // List.Values['ToZip']
    // List.Values['CallSid']
    // List.Values['To']
    // List.Values['CallerZip']
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, in Delphi 5, none of those properties existed yet, so you will have to do everything manually:

```pascal
Function TwilioSignatureValidate(twilioSignature: string; QueryString: string ; Url: string): boolean;
var
  List: TStringList;

  // the following are tweaked from TStrings in later Delphi versions...

  procedure MySetDelimitedText(const Value: string);
  var
    P, P1: PChar;
    S: string;
  begin
    List.BeginUpdate;
    try
      List.Clear;
      P := PChar(Value);
      while P^ <> #0 do
      begin
        if P^ = '"' then
          S := AnsiExtractQuotedStr(P, '"')
        else
        begin
          P1 := P;
          while (P^ <> #0) and (P^ <> '&') do
            P := CharNext(P);
          SetString(S, P1, P - P1);
        end;
        List.Add(S);
        if P^ = '&' then
        begin
          P := CharNext(P);
          if P^ = #0 then
            List.Add('');
        end;
      end;
    finally
      List.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;

  function MyIndexOfName(const Name: string): Integer;
  var
    P: Integer;
    S: string;
  begin
    for Result := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      S := List.Strings[Result];
      P := AnsiPos('=', S);
      if (P <> 0) and (AnsiCompareStr(Copy(S, 1, P - 1), Name) = 0) then Exit;
    end;
    Result := -1;
  end;

  function MyGetValue(const Name: string): string;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    I := MyIndexOfName(Name);
    if I >= 0 then
      Result := Copy(List.Strings[I], Length(Name) + 2, MaxInt) else
      Result := '';
  end;

begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    MySetDelimitedText(QueryString);

    // use MyGetValue('param name') as needed, eg:
    // MyGetValue('Called')
    // MyGetValue('ToState')
    // MyGetValue('CallerCountry')
    // MyGetValue('Direction')
    // MyGetValue('CallerState')
    // MyGetValue('ToZip')
    // MyGetValue('CallSid')
    // MyGetValue('To')
    // MyGetValue('CallerZip')
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I am getting errors like this when trying to using the Tstring properties.  [Error] TwilioSignatureValidateFunctions.pas(49): Undeclared identifier: 'CaseSensitive'

Comment: @brucecopper Sorry, my bad, I forgot that `Delimiter`, `DelimitedText`, and `CaseSensitive` were added in Delphi 6.  I have updated my answer

Comment: That worked great, Do you know of a way to sort this list Alphabetically?

Comment: @brucecopper `TStringList` in Delphi 5 has a `Sorted` property, as well as `Sort()` and `CustomSort()` methods. However, `Sorted` and `Sort()` do not take `name=value` pairs into account to sort only on the `name`, they sort on the entire strings, so if you want to sort on `name` only then you have to use `CustomSort()` for that.